# Mi app crashea cuando de AppCompatActivity a Fragment

Tags: android, android-studio

estaba siguiendo un tutorial ya que soy nuevo desarrollando app en Android Studio, y vi que mi clase tenia `extends AppCompatActivity`, por lo que decidi cambiarlo por `extends Fragment`, sin que, dentro de la clase, me muestre un error.

El problema es que cuando ejecuto la aplicación, se me abre correctamente, pero cuando quiero mostrar la vista que pertenece a ese Fragment, la app crashea, es decir, se cierra sola y frena la depuración. Eh intentado poner breakpoints pero la app se cierra antes.

Esta es mi clase:

```
public class Registrarse extends Fragment {

    private EditText dni;
    private EditText contrasenia;
    private EditText peso;
    private EditText altura;
    private EditText sexo;
    private EditText mail;
    private UserBusiness userBusiness;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_registrarse, container, false);
        dni = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.idDni);
        contrasenia = (EditText)  view.findViewById(R.id.idContrasnia);
        peso = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.idPeso);
        altura = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.idAltura);
        sexo = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.idSexo);
        mail = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.idMail);
        return view;
    }
```

Y ésta es mi vista principal o `main_activity`:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

    public void Registrarse(View view){
        Intent register = new Intent(this, Registrarse.class);
        startActivity(register);
    }

    public void MenuPrincipal(View view){
        Intent menu = new Intent(this, MenuPrincipal.class);
        startActivity(menu);
    }

    public void Prueba(View view){
        Intent menu = new Intent(this, EjercicioSeleccionado.class);
        startActivity(menu);
    }
}
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Para aquellos que no puedan ver la foto, es mi emulador con un popup diciendo: `'Nutrain keeps stopping'`

Alguien me puede ayudar a ver el problema?

vi que el problema era porque tenía `startActivity()` en lugar de `startService()`, así que cambié pero ahora no falla pero no pasa nada, osea toco el botón pero no redirige ni hace nada, ni muestra mensaje en el `LogCat`

Comment: ¿Qué error recibes? Al ejecutar la aplicación deberías ver algún mensaje de error en el Logcat o Run.

Answer (score 0):

Creo que tu error es porque metes un fragment en el intent, y los intent solo manejan Activities.

https://developer.android.com/guide/components/intents-filters?hl=es-419

para utilizar fragments, necesitas hacer un navHostFragment(buscalo) y ahí dentro del host, empezar a utilizarlos